# new gwt interface automation testing

Tags: gwt, automation, web-scraping

So our front end GUI is getting a large overhaul to a new GWT based application. I have been working on creating the automation scripts for the old front end using cURL in some tcl/expect scripts. As I have looking at the new app I am starting to realize more and more that cURL is out of the question for performing these web interactions and was wondering if anybody had some ideas/experience with testing a web app made with GWT??
Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest analogy to cURL tests for a static-page UI for a dynamic JS/GWT UI will be [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) (or [Webdriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/09_webdriver.html)) tests.  Selenium tests load the page up in a real browser, including all JS, and simulate clicking on and interacting with UI elements and tests that they react accordingly.

That being said, unit tests should also be written to test the functionality of your GWT UI without having to load the page in a browser, just testing that the underlying Java/JS performs correctly.  [The MVP pattern](http://code.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/GoogleWebToolkitBestPractices.html) aims to make this easier/quicker.

Comment: I know this is old but I came back to work for this company again this summer as an intern and have found selenium, along with a new found knowledge in DOM parsing as the answers to this problem